# /usr/local/bin No such file or directory

Tags: macos, ssh

/usr/local/bin is not found on my mac computer. I already ran

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

and still not /usr/local/bin. I am trying to install ssh-copy-id by following https://github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX but it fails when trying to move ssh-copy-id to /usr/local/bin. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should be able to create it yourself by executing `sudo mkdir -p -m 775 /usr/local/bin` from the terminal. If `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `$PATH` environmental variable, you can update it by appending `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` to the file `$HOME/.bash_profile`. Close your current terminal, and open a new one for testing.

UPDATE: If you have brew installed, you can just run `brew install ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: Thank you, however when I install ssh-copy-id by using the above link it now installs but when I run it I get :  /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: line 1: ucgi:: command not found
stat: script:: stat: No such file or directory
stat: No: stat: No such file or directory
stat: such: stat: No such file or directory
stat: file: stat: No such file or directory
stat: or: stat: No such file or directory
stat: directory: stat: No such file or directory                   Any idea why?

Comment: @Technic1an You might have to update your `$PATH` environmental variable to include `/usr/local/bin`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: when searching for .bash_profile it says there is no such file

Comment: @Technic1an Try create it in your home folder assuming you are run bash shell.

Comment: @Technic1an If you have [brew](http://brew.sh/) installed, you can just run `brew install ssh-copy-id`